# Automatic sequential filenames for Omnigraffle canvases

Tags: omnigraffle, canvas

Is there a way to automatically name the canvas in Omnigraffle sequentially based on their position? Any applescript or plugin?

Such as idea 1, idea 2, idea 3, etc. And if I move it, it'll use new position as part of name and update the others to be sequential (canvas numbering adjustment).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I used an Applescript to do this after going through these sites:

- http://www.j-schell.de/node/153
- http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automation/if-and-if-else-applescript-conditional-statements/
- http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=22828
- http://mac-os-x.10953.n7.nabble.com/AppleScript-loop-works-only-the-first-time-td34104.html
- http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=17447
- http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=24079

---

```
tell application "OmniGraffle Professional 5"
    activate
    set theDocument to front document
    set theCanvases to every canvas of theDocument
    set canvasCount to count of canvases of theDocument
    repeat with canvasNumber from 1 to canvasCount
        set canvasNumber to canvasNumber as number
        if canvasNumber < 10 then
            set dd to "0" & canvasNumber
        else
            set dd to canvasNumber
        end if
        set name of canvas canvasNumber of theDocument to "Mockup " & dd
        set canvas of front window to canvas canvasNumber of theDocument
    end repeat
end tell
```